# Kendo Grid case sensitive sorting - how to sort by A a B b C c on MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sorting, kendo-grid, case-sensitive

I have an issue with the case sensitivity of the sorting: it sorts A B C a b c.
How to get A a B b C c sorting?
I use Kendo grid for MVC.

```
<%:Html.Kendo().Grid(Of CompanyPriorityRowModel)().
Name("CompanyPriorityGrid").
Columns(Sub(columns)
        columns.Bound(Function(p) p.Idx).Hidden(True)
        columns.Bound(Function(p) p.CompanyName).
            HeaderTemplate("Company Name").
            HeaderHtmlAttributes(New With {.class = "col-xs-2"})
        columns.Bound(Function(p) p.CompanyId).
            HeaderTemplate("Company Id").
            HeaderHtmlAttributes(New With {.class = "col-xs-2"})
   End Sub).
Sortable().
Resizable(Function(o) o.Columns(True)).
Pageable(Function(pageable) pageable.ButtonCount(5).PageSizes(New Integer(2){10, 25, 50})).
AutoBind(False).
Events(Function(o) o.DataBound("JobPriorityGridJs.dataBound")).
Filterable().
DataSource(Function(datasource) datasource.
Ajax().
PageSize(10).
ServerOperation(False).
Read(Function(read) read.Action("ReadCompaniesPriority", "JobPriority").
Data("JobPriorityGridJs.GridAdditionalData"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function work out very good for me:

https://gist.github.com/JohannesHoppe/4161255